# mach_vm_map failed (error code=3)

Tags: xamarin.ios, crash, malloc, xamarin

After navigating through my iPAD application for a while I have noticed that the responsiveness of the app is getting slower and slower and finally my app crashes with the following error

```
    AppName(1779,0x3d12d18c) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=167936) failed (error code=3)
    *** error: can't allocate region
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    Jan  7 11:34:30  AppName[1779] <Error>:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
    Jan  7 11:34:30  AppName[1779] <Error>:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) <0x0012b>
    Jan  7 11:34:30  AppName[1779] <Error>:   at AppName.Application.Main (string[]) <0x0002f>
    Jan  7 11:34:30  AppName[1779] <Error>:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
```

is this a memory related issue?

Comment: sounds like you developed your app with mono. Either the problem is in the mono framework (good luck) or in your app and most likely you try to allocate too big a memory region

Comment: the problem was in a third party component which was updating the UI throught a for loop that did calculations

Comment: which 3rd party component?

Comment: It should probably not come as a huge surprise that memory _corruption_ can also cause this. I just got the same error in a C++ program running on OS X, well before it got around to allocating any significant amount of memory. Root cause in my case was a write off the end of a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is a memory issue: you ran out of memory.

I suggest you [use Instruments](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/using_instruments_to_detect_native_leaks_using_markheap/) to try to track down any memory leaks.

Comment: I just got this same error message, but my app is only using 13 MB of memory (0.08% of available).

Comment: Xcode has been acting *very* weirdly for me lately though. I hope this is a transient issue.

Comment: I got same issue my app uses 13.6MB but app is crash on navigate and back multiple time from one view to another