# Error using boost serialization with binary archive

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-serialization, ntl

I get the following error while reading from `boost::archive::binary_iarchive` into my variable:

```
test-serialization(9285,0x11c62fdc0) malloc: can't allocate region
*** mach_vm_map(size=18014398509486080) failed (error code=3)
test-serialization(9285,0x11c62fdc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

My serialization and deserialization code are:

```cpp
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & archive, const helib::PubKey & pubkey, const unsigned int version){
  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("inside save_construct_data");
  archive << &(pubkey.context);
  archive << pubkey.skBounds;
  archive << pubkey.keySwitching;
  archive << pubkey.keySwitchMap;
  archive << pubkey.KS_strategy;
  archive << pubkey.recryptKeyID;
}

template<class Archive>
void load_construct_data(Archive & archive, helib::PubKey * pubkey, const unsigned int version){
  helib::Context * context = new helib::Context(2,3,1); //random numbers since there is no default constructor
  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("deserializing context");
  archive >> context;
  std::vector<double> skBounds;
  std::vector<helib::KeySwitch> keySwitching;
  std::vector<std::vector<long>> keySwitchMap;
  NTL::Vec<long> KS_strategy;
  long recryptKeyID;
  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("deserializing skbounds");
  archive >> skBounds;
  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("deserializing keyswitching");
  archive >> keySwitching;
  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("deserializing keyswitchmap");
  archive >> keySwitchMap;
  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("deserializing KS_strategy");
  archive >> KS_strategy;
  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("deserializing recryptKeyID");
  archive >> recryptKeyID;
  BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("new pubkey");
  ::new(pubkey)helib::PubKey(*context);
  //TODO: complete
}

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & archive, helib::PubKey & pubkey, const unsigned int version){
  split_free(archive, pubkey, version);
}

template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & archive, helib::PubKey & pubkey, const unsigned int version){
}
```

The test that calls the code is the following:

```cpp
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(serialization_pubkey)
{
  auto context = helibTestContext();
  helib::SecKey secret_key(context);
  secret_key.GenSecKey();
  // Compute key-switching matrices that we need
  helib::addSome1DMatrices(secret_key);
  // Set the secret key (upcast: SecKey is a subclass of PubKey)
  const helib::PubKey& original_pubkey = secret_key;

  std::string filename = "pubkey.serialized";

  std::ofstream os(filename, std::ios::binary);
  {
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oarchive(os);
    oarchive << original_pubkey;
  }

  helib::PubKey * restored_pubkey = new helib::PubKey(helib::Context(2,3,1));
  {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarchive(ifs);
    BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT("calling deserialization");
    iarchive >> restored_pubkey;
    BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT("done with deserialization");

    //tests ommitted
  }
}
```

Considerations:

1. Serialization works both fine with `boost::archive::text_oarchive` and `boost::archive::binary_oarchive`. They create a file of 46M and 21M respectively (big, I know).
2. Deserialization with `boost::archive::text_iarchive` basically stopped at the execution of `archive >> keySwitching;` The process gets automatically killed. This is in fact the biggest part of the archive.
3. I decided to try with `boost::archive::binary_iarchive` since the file is half the size, but I get the error shown at the beginning. The error happens while executing the first read from the archive: `archive >> context;`.
4. The asymmetry between input and output (`save` and `load_construct_data`) is because I could not find another way to avoid the implementation of the serialization of a derived class of `helib::PubKey`. Using a pointer to `helib::PubKey` was giving me compilation errors asking for the serialization of the derived class. If there is some other way I'm all ears.

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**:

I am implementing deserialization for some classes in the cryptographic library [HElib](https://github.com/homenc/HElib) because I need to send ciphertext over the wire. One of these classes is `helib::PubKey`. I'm using the [boost serialization library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for the implementation. I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/giancarloGiuffra/f7da5e7f856be6eb64a1069cc1afbf22) to provide a reprex as suggested in the comments. There are 3 files:

1. *serialization.hpp*, it contains the serialiation implementation. Unfortunately, `helib::PubKey` depends on many other classes making the file rather long. All the other classes have unit tests that pass. **Furthermore, I had to make a tiny modification to the class with the goal of serializing it. I made public the private members**.
2. *test-serialization.cpp*, it contains the unit test.
3. *Makefile*. Running make creates the executable *test-serialization*.

Comment: This probable seems to be an error caused by your own code, the fact that your question is [not a complete minimized example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) lets me suspect this even further. For example the definition of `helib::PubKey` is missing.

Comment: @Superlokkus I have updated the question providing more context and hopefully a reprex.

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970417/mach-vm-map-failed-error-code-3) to see if you have a same problem

Comment: Re: non-intrusive serialization of privates: see [`serialization::access`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html) and these methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30595430/85371

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`vector<bool>` strikes again</strike>

It's actually allocating for 0x1fffffffff20000 bits (that's 144 petabits) on my test box. That's coming directly from IndexSet::resize().

Now I have serious questions about HElib using `std::vector<bool>` here (it seems they would be *far* better served with something like `boost::icl::interval_set<>`).
 [image]

Well. That was a wild goose chase (that IndexSet serialization can be much improved). However, the real problem is that you had [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you don't deserialize the same type as you serialize.

You serialize a `PubKey`, but attempt to deserialize as `PubKey*`. Uhoh.

Now beyond that, there's quite a bit of problems:

- You had to modify the library to make private members public. This can easily violate ODR (making the class layout incompatible).
- You seem to treat the context as a "dynamic" resource, which will engage [Object Tracking](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking). This could be a viable approach. BUT. You'll have to think about ownership.

  It seems like you didn't do that yet. For example, the line in `load_construct_data` for `DoublCRT` is a definite memory-leak:

  ```
  helib::Context * context = new helib::Context(2,3,1);
  ```

  You never use it nor ever free it. In fact, you simply overwrite it with the deserialized instance, which *may or may not* be owned. Catch-22

  Exactly the same happens in `load_construct_data` for `PubKey`.
- worse, in `save_construct_data` you completely gratuitously copy context objects for each `DoubleCRT` in each `SecKey`:

  ```
   auto context = polynomial->getContext();
   archive << &context;
  ```

  Because you *fake* it out as pointer-serialization, again (obviously useless) object tracking kicks in, just meaning you serialize redundant `Context` copies which will will be ***all*** be leaked un deserialization.
- I'd be tempted to assume the context instances in both would always be the same? Why not serialize the context(s) separately anyways?
- In fact I went and analyzed the HElib source code to check these assumptions. It turns out I was correct. Nothing ever constructs a context outside

  ```
  std::unique_ptr<Context> buildContextFromBinary(std::istream& str);
  std::unique_ptr<Context> buildContextFromAscii(std::istream& str);
  ```

  As you can see, they return owned pointers. You should have been using them. Perhaps even with the built-in serialization, that I practically stumble over here.

### Time To Regroup

I'd use the serialization code from HElib (because, why reinvent the wheel and make a ton of bugs doing so?). If you **insist** on integration with Boost Serialization, you can have your cake and eat it:

```
template <class Archive> void save(Archive& archive, const helib::PubKey& pubkey, unsigned) {
    using V = std::vector<char>;
    using D = iostreams::back_insert_device<V>;
    V data;
    {
        D dev(data);
        iostreams::stream_buffer<D> sbuf(dev);
        std::ostream os(&sbuf); // expose as std::ostream
        helib::writePubKeyBinary(os, pubkey);
    }
    archive << data;
}

template <class Archive> void load(Archive& archive, helib::PubKey& pubkey, unsigned) {
    std::vector<char> data;
    archive >> data;
    using S = iostreams::array_source;
    S source(data.data(), data.size());
    iostreams::stream_buffer<S> sbuf(source);
    {
        std::istream is(&sbuf); // expose as std::istream
        helib::readPubKeyBinary(is, pubkey);
    }
}
```

That's all. 24 lines of code. And it's gonna be tested and maintained by the library authors. You can't beat that (clearly). I've modified the tests a bit so we don't abuse private details anymore.

### Cleaning Up The Code

By separating out a helper to deal with the blob writing, we can implement different `helib` types in a very similar way:

```
namespace helib { // leverage ADL
    template <class A> void save(A& ar, const Context& o, unsigned) {
        Blob data = to_blob(o, writeContextBinary);
        ar << data;
    }
    template <class A> void load(A& ar, Context& o, unsigned) {
        Blob data;
        ar >> data;
        from_blob(data, o, readContextBinary);
    }
    template <class A> void save(A& ar, const PubKey& o, unsigned) {
        Blob data = to_blob(o, writePubKeyBinary);
        ar << data;
    }
    template <class A> void load(A& ar, PubKey& o, unsigned) {
        Blob data;
        ar >> data;
        from_blob(data, o, readPubKeyBinary);
    }
}
```

This is elegance to me.

### FULL LISTING

I have cloned a new gist https://gist.github.com/sehe/ba82a0329e4ec586363eb82d3f3b9326 that includes the following change-sets:

```
0079c07 Make it compile locally
b3b2cf1 Squelch the warnings
011b589 Endof investigations, regroup time

f4d79a6 Reimplemented using HElib binary IO
a403e97 Bitwise reproducible outputs
```

Only the last two commits contains changes related to the actual fixes.

I'll list the full code here too for posterity. There are a number of subtle reorganizations and ditto comments in the test code. You'd do well to read through them carefully to see whether you understand them and the implications suit your needs. I left comments describing why the test assertions are what they are to help.

- File `serialization.hpp`

  ```
  #ifndef EVOTING_SERIALIZATION_H
  #define EVOTING_SERIALIZATION_H

  #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE main
  #include <helib/helib.h>
  #include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
  #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
  #include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>
  #include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
  #include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>

  namespace /* file-static */ {
      using Blob = std::vector<char>;

      template <typename T, typename F>
      Blob to_blob(const T& object, F writer) {
          using D = boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<Blob>;
          Blob data;
          {
              D dev(data);
              boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<D> sbuf(dev);
              std::ostream os(&sbuf); // expose as std::ostream
              writer(os, object);
          }
          return data;
      }

      template <typename T, typename F>
      void from_blob(Blob const& data, T& object, F reader) {
          boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<boost::iostreams::array_source>
              sbuf(data.data(), data.size());
          std::istream is(&sbuf); // expose as std::istream
          reader(is, object);
      }
  }

  namespace helib { // leverage ADL
      template <class A> void save(A& ar, const Context& o, unsigned) {
          Blob data = to_blob(o, writeContextBinary);
          ar << data;
      }
      template <class A> void load(A& ar, Context& o, unsigned) {
          Blob data;
          ar >> data;
          from_blob(data, o, readContextBinary);
      }
      template <class A> void save(A& ar, const PubKey& o, unsigned) {
          Blob data = to_blob(o, writePubKeyBinary);
          ar << data;
      }
      template <class A> void load(A& ar, PubKey& o, unsigned) {
          Blob data;
          ar >> data;
          from_blob(data, o, readPubKeyBinary);
      }
  }

  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(helib::Context)
  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(helib::PubKey)
  #endif //EVOTING_SERIALIZATION_H
  ```
- File `test-serialization.cpp`

  ```
  #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE main
  #include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
  #include <helib/helib.h>
  #include <fstream>
  #include "serialization.hpp"
  #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
  #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
  #include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
  #include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

  helib::Context helibTestMinimalContext(){
    // Plaintext prime modulus
    unsigned long p = 4999;
    // Cyclotomic polynomial - defines phi(m)
    unsigned long m = 32109;
    // Hensel lifting (default = 1)
    unsigned long r = 1;
    return helib::Context(m, p, r);
  }

  helib::Context helibTestContext(){
    auto context = helibTestMinimalContext();

    // Number of bits of the modulus chain
    unsigned long bits = 300;
    // Number of columns of Key-Switching matix (default = 2 or 3)
    unsigned long c = 2;

    // Modify the context, adding primes to the modulus chain
    buildModChain(context, bits, c);
    return context;
  }

  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(serialization_pubkey) {
      auto context = helibTestContext();
      helib::SecKey secret_key(context);
      secret_key.GenSecKey();
      // Compute key-switching matrices that we need
      helib::addSome1DMatrices(secret_key);
      // Set the secret key (upcast: SecKey is a subclass of PubKey)
      const helib::PubKey& original_pubkey = secret_key;

      std::string const filename = "pubkey.serialized";

      {
          std::ofstream os(filename, std::ios::binary);
          boost::archive::binary_oarchive oarchive(os);
          oarchive << context << original_pubkey;
      }
      {
          // just checking reproducible output
          std::ofstream os(filename + ".2", std::ios::binary);
          boost::archive::binary_oarchive oarchive(os);
          oarchive << context << original_pubkey;
      }

      // reading back to independent instances of Context/PubKey
      {
          // NOTE: if you start from something rogue, it will fail with PAlgebra mismatch.
          helib::Context surrogate = helibTestMinimalContext();

          std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
          boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarchive(ifs);
          iarchive >> surrogate;

          // we CAN test that the contexts end up matching
          BOOST_TEST((context == surrogate));

          helib::SecKey independent(surrogate);
          helib::PubKey& indep_pk = independent;
          iarchive >> indep_pk;
          // private again, as it should be, but to understand the relation:
          // BOOST_TEST((&independent.context == &surrogate));

          // The library's operator== compares the reference, so it would say "not equal"
          BOOST_TEST((indep_pk != original_pubkey));
          {
              // just checking reproducible output
              std::ofstream os(filename + ".3", std::ios::binary);
              boost::archive::binary_oarchive oarchive(os);
              oarchive << surrogate << indep_pk;
          }
      }

      // doing it the other way (sharing the context):
      {
          helib::PubKey restored_pubkey(context);
          {
              std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
              boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarchive(ifs);
              iarchive >> context >> restored_pubkey;
          }
          // now `operator==` confirms equality
          BOOST_TEST((restored_pubkey == original_pubkey));

          {
              // just checking reproducible output
              std::ofstream os(filename + ".4", std::ios::binary);
              boost::archive::binary_oarchive oarchive(os);
              oarchive << context << restored_pubkey;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

### TEST OUTPUT

```
time ./test-serialization -l all -r detailed
Running 1 test case...
Entering test module "main"
test-serialization.cpp(34): Entering test case "serialization_pubkey"
test-serialization.cpp(61): info: check (context == surrogate) has passed
test-serialization.cpp(70): info: check (indep_pk != original_pubkey) has passed
test-serialization.cpp(82): info: check (restored_pubkey == original_pubkey) has passed
test-serialization.cpp(34): Leaving test case "serialization_pubkey"; testing time: 36385217us
Leaving test module "main"; testing time: 36385273us

Test module "main" has passed with:
  1 test case out of 1 passed
  3 assertions out of 3 passed

  Test case "serialization_pubkey" has passed with:
    3 assertions out of 3 passed

real    0m36,698s
user    0m35,558s
sys     0m0,850s
```

### Bitwise Reproducible Outputs

On repeated serialization it appears that indeed the output is bitwise identical, which may be an important property:

```
sha256sum pubkey.serialized*
66b95adbd996b100bff58774e066e7a309e70dff7cbbe08b5c77b9fa0f63c97f  pubkey.serialized
66b95adbd996b100bff58774e066e7a309e70dff7cbbe08b5c77b9fa0f63c97f  pubkey.serialized.2
66b95adbd996b100bff58774e066e7a309e70dff7cbbe08b5c77b9fa0f63c97f  pubkey.serialized.3
66b95adbd996b100bff58774e066e7a309e70dff7cbbe08b5c77b9fa0f63c97f  pubkey.serialized.4
```

Note that it is (obviously) not identical across runs (because it generates different key material).

### Side Quest (The Wild Goose Chase)

One way to improve the IndexSet serialization code manually is to also use `vector<bool>`:

```
template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & archive, const helib::IndexSet & index_set, const unsigned int version){
        std::vector<bool> elements;
        elements.resize(index_set.last()-index_set.first()+1);
        for (auto n : index_set)
            elements[n-index_set.first()] = true;
        archive << index_set.first() << elements;
    }

template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & archive, helib::IndexSet & index_set, const unsigned int version){
        long first_ = 0;
        std::vector<bool> elements;
        archive >> first_ >> elements;
        index_set.clear();
        for (size_t n = 0; n < elements.size(); ++n) {
            if (elements[n])
                index_set.insert(n+first_);
        }
    }
```

Better idea would be to use `dynamic_bitset` (for which I happen to have [contributed the serialization code](https://github.com/boostorg/dynamic_bitset/pull/14) (see [How to serialize boost::dynamic_bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006792/how-to-serialize-boostdynamic-bitset/31015623#31015623))):

```
template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & archive, const helib::IndexSet & index_set, const unsigned int version){
        boost::dynamic_bitset<> elements;
        elements.resize(index_set.last()-index_set.first()+1);
        for (auto n : index_set)
            elements.set(n-index_set.first());
        archive << index_set.first() << elements;
    }

template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & archive, helib::IndexSet & index_set, const unsigned int version) {
        long first_ = 0;
        boost::dynamic_bitset<> elements;
        archive >> first_ >> elements;
        index_set.clear();
        for (size_t n = elements.find_first(); n != -1; n = elements.find_next(n))
            index_set.insert(n+first_);
    }
```

> *Of course, you would likely have to do similar things for `IndexMap`.*